# How to get the name of a message sent by a hangout bot

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

At hangout chat bots when a user added to space or removed or someone sent a message an event sent to bot while I can respond with a JSON object {text: "Any thing"}.
If I need to remove or update this message I need it's name.
How to get this message name?

Comment: did you figure it out ? having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You should get it from `message` field in the request body of the event. Something like:

```
var messageName = req.body.message.name;
```

Here you have an example I found from the documentation:

```
{
  "type": "MESSAGE",
  "eventTime": "2017-03-02T19:02:59.910959Z",
  "space": {
    "name": "spaces/AAAAAAAAAAA",
    "displayName": "Chuck Norris Discussion Room",
    "type": "ROOM"
  },
  "message": {
    "name": "spaces/AAAAAAAAAAA/messages/CCCCCCCCCCC",
    "sender": {
      "name": "users/12345678901234567890",
      "displayName": "Chuck Norris",
      "avatarUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/.../photo.jpg",
      "email": "chuck@example.com"
    },
    "createTime": "2017-03-02T19:02:59.910959Z",
    "text": "@TestBot Violence is my last option.",
    "argumentText": " Violence is my last option.",
    "thread": {
      "name": "spaces/AAAAAAAAAAA/threads/BBBBBBBBBBB"
    },
    "annotations": [
      {
        "length": 8,
        "startIndex": 0,
        "userMention": {
          "type": "MENTION",
          "user": {
            "avatarUrl": "https://.../avatar.png",
            "displayName": "TestBot",
            "name": "users/1234567890987654321",
            "type": "BOT"
          }
        },
        "type": "USER_MENTION"
      }
    ],
  },
  "user": {
    "name": "users/12345678901234567890",
    "displayName": "Chuck Norris",
    "avatarUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/.../photo.jpg",
    "email": "chuck@example.com"
  }
}
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/events#message

Comment: nah he's talking about he's bot message name (the one it sent), what you get in the request body is the user message name (the one you receive).